# Using image styles with Scald dnd (Drupal 7)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have been using the Scald module for few months now, with great experience.  But there is one thing I haven't quite figured out yet.

When I have Drag'n'Drop enabled for a textarea (with CKEditor) I can drag images into the textarea and it displays in it's original size.  If i Right-click the image I get the image properties for the image, but only at CSS level.

I'm trying to figure out how to add an Image Style to the image, so that my 4000x3000 image that I drag into the editor will be scaled down to a nicer 300x200 image where wanted, and therefor save some valuable bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer after a pile of googling and reading through few articles.  First and foremost it was the one about installing and configuring Scald.  (Please Google, I can't post that many links :(  )

I installed the CKEditor module, disabled the Wysiwyg module, downloaded the library into sites/all/libraries/, and finally read this article about contexts with Scald:  https://drupal.org/node/2104651.

Bottom line, this is possible, but not easy (as sometimes Scald is), but when you get the hang of it, it's much better than the Media module.

Answer (score 0):

I just struggled with this so thought I'd document how to set up contexts.

This is how you add new contexts which can use an image style formatter as a transcoder using the UI:

1. Go to /admin/structure/scald and click add context.  Choose any name and details, but do check "Make parseable"
2. On the top of the original page for scald settings click "Contexts" in the upper right for "Image" under "Scald Unified Atom Types"
3. In the page that loads (/admin/structure/scald/image/contexts) you'll see your new context named.  Open the fieldset and change the "Transcoder" from "Passthrough" to one of your image styles, e.g. "Large (image style)"

Now when you right-click on a image atom in a textarea wysiwyg and choose "Edit Atom Properties" you'll get a dialog with a new context to choose from.  You can also go the default contexts provided by Scald and change them from "Passthrough" to one of your image styles.

Also, at the moment you also have to apply this change https://drupal.org/node/2046545 to scald.pages.inc or you'll lose your legend as you switch contexts or use the dev version.  When 7.x-1.2 is released this will no longer be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across this same issue, using WYSIWYG 2.x-dev with CKEditor library 4.3, Scald 1.2. What fixed it was one of these things (sorry can't remember exactly which one):

- Both "Scald DnD Integration" and "Scald SAS conversion" enabled in the relevant WYSIWYG profiles
- The display settings for your image (at admin/structure/scald/image/display) have atom field set to enabled but image field set to hidden

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the insert image module

https://drupal.org/project/insert

The easiest way to assign image styles to images going into a wysiwyg area

Comment: I can't see any configuration for Scald with that module, it seems to work only with the Media module.